# Task cancellation with Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a function that invokes set of functions which make some long running network calls (that run heavy queries). Now I have a timeout placed which dictates that if the operation times out, then all operations need to be abandoned asap.
This is where I am stuck and struggling, my operations keep running despite invoking cts.Cancel() and OperationCanceledException or TaskCanceledException isn't raised in called methods while using Task.Delay ensures each time in case of timeout, my operations are cancelled (as Exception is raised) else

Refer to my code where GetAllProductCodesForReleaseAsync() is the one that invokes the operations and one such operation performing a long running task is GetPackageReportsCustomer()

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductCodeDTO>> GetAllProductCodesForReleaseAsync(int releaseId, int packageId)
{
  using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
  {
     var GetReleaseReportsTask = GetReleaseRelatedReports(releaseId, cts.Token);
     var GetPackageReportsCustomerTask = GetPackageReportsCustomer(packageId, releaseId, cts.Token);
     Tasks tasks = Task.WhenAll(GetPackageReportsCustomerTask, GetReleaseReportsTask);
     var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks, Task.Delay(3000)).ConfigureAwait(false);// 3s timeout
     if (!tasks.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
     {
          // Timeout occurred, cancel the tasks
          cts.Cancel();
          this.logger.LogError($"Unable to get reports due to timeout for ReleaseId {releaseId}");
     }
                    
          await completedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<PackageReportsCustomerDTO>> GetPackageReportsCustomer(int packageId, int releaseId, CancellationToken ct)
{
      IEnumerable<PackageReportsCustomerDTO> packageReportsOfCustomer = new List<PackageReportsCustomerDTO>();
      try
      {
          ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          this.logger.LogWarning("Inside GetPackageReportsCustomer");
          packageReportsOfCustomer = await this.database.GetPackageReportsCustomerWithSmartPages(packageId).ConfigureAwait(false);
          await Task.Delay(10, ct);
          this.logger.LogWarning("Inside GetPackageReportsCustomer END");
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
      {
          this.logger.LogWarning($"Abandoning task due to timeout for ReleaseId {releaseId}");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          this.logger.LogWarning($"Unexpected error with ReleaseId {releaseId}");
      }
      return packageReportsOfCustomer;
}
```

Interestingly if I remove Task.Delay(10, ct), OperationCanceledException is never raised while its addition makes sure each time my this method takes longer than time specified in Tasks.WhenAny(), this exception is raised...
Can someone enlighten me exactly what's going on and if there's a better way to refactor this. Note that I do need to make and consume my methods async/await

**UPDATE** I found that if I remove Task.Delay(10, ct) and instead move ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() after my awaited task, it works fine... below is updated code for ref:

```
this.logger.LogWarning("Inside GetPackageReportsCustomer");
packageReportsOfCustomer = await this.database.GetPackageReportsCustomerWithSmartPages(packageId).ConfigureAwait(false);
ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
this.logger.LogWarning("Inside GetPackageReportsCustomer END");
```

Comment: `await this.database.GetPackageReportsCustomerWithSmartPages` you need to pass in the cancellation token here

Comment: thnx... I had tried that too but didn't work...

Comment: @user2128341 in short - tasks in C# supports cooperative cancellation, if one is not analyzing the passed token "correctly" there is no easy way to cancel it.

Comment: Well what does `GetPackageReportsCustomerWithSmartPages` actually do? Can it handle the cancellation token?

Comment: @Charlieface GetPackageReportsCustomerWithSmartPages can handle the token as it also has ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() however still the above described behavior is exhibited... Also pls refer to the Update I posted

Comment: @guruStrong how can I analyze the token if all I hv in the method is something like var result = await this.connection.QueryAsync<PackageReportsCustomer>(sQuery, new { packageId }); return result;
All I have is an awaited task and I'm not sure how to analyze the token in such a case

Comment: Unless you show that code I can't help. No it sounds like you need to push the cancellation token deeper, presumably all the way to whatever database call you are making.

Comment: @Charlieface 
```
var result = await this.connection.QueryAsync<PackageReportsCustomer>(sQuery, new { packageId }); 
return result;
```

Comment: If you are using Dapper then use a `CommandDefinition` to pass the token. So use `var result = await this.connection.QueryAsync<PackageReportsCustomer>(new CommandDefinition(sQuery, new { packageId }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken));`